# Garbage value not sure where its coming from

Tags: c

I have a problem with my code somewhere I have been at it for a few hours now trying to spot the problem but can not determine the cause. When I print to the screen all values should equal zero but instead the `angleY` variable keeps printing out `34244` when it should be zero. I would like to see if anyone can tell me where this value is coming from and why? I have the line `printf("current rate: %d angle rate: %d angle rate: %d previous rate: %d \n",currentRateY, angleRateY, angleY, previousRateY);` that prints the values of all variables so I can pinpoint the problem and all variables remain `0` until the `angleY` variable. My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>

#define CTRL_REG1 0x20
#define CTRL_REG2 0x21
#define CTRL_REG3 0x22
#define CTRL_REG4 0x23


int fd;
short x = 0;
short y = 0;
short z = 0;
int main (){



    fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(0x69); // I2C address of gyro
    wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd, CTRL_REG1, 0x1F); //Turn on all axes, disable power down
    wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd, CTRL_REG3, 0x08); //Enable control ready signal
    wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd, CTRL_REG4, 0x80); // Set scale (500 deg/sec)
    delay(200);                    // Wait to synchronize

void getGyroValues (){
    int MSB, LSB;

    LSB = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x28);
    MSB = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x29);
    x = ((MSB << 8) | LSB);

    MSB = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x2B);
    LSB = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x2A);
    y = ((MSB << 8) | LSB);

    MSB = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x2D);
    LSB = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x2C);
    z = ((MSB << 8) | LSB);
}
    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){

        getGyroValues();

    int previousRateZ = z /114;
    int previousRateY = y /114;
    int previousRateX = x /114;

        delay(100);

        getGyroValues();

    int currentRateZ = z /114;
    int currentRateY = y /114;
    int currentRateX = x /114;

    int angleRateZ = ((long)(previousRateZ + currentRateZ) * 105)/1000;
    int angleRateY = ((long)(previousRateY + currentRateY) * 105)/1000;
    int angleRateX = ((long)(previousRateX + currentRateX) * 105)/1000;

    int angleZ = angleZ + angleRateZ;
    int angleY = angleY + angleRateY;
    int angleX = angleX + angleRateX;
    printf("current rate: %d angle rate: %d angle rate: %d previous rate: %d \n",currentRateY, angleRateY, angleY, previousRateY);
        delay(100);

    if(i == 1){
        printf("Z equals: %d\n", angleZ);
        printf("Y equals: %d\n", angleY);
    printf("X equals: %d\n", angleX);
    i=0;
    }
}


};
```

Comment: what about values of angleX, angleZ - are they zero or also have unexpected values?

Comment: the culprits:   int angleZ = angleZ + angleRateZ;
    int angleY = angleY + angleRateY;
    int angleX = angleX + angleRateX;

Comment: I somehow know this is for a quad-rotor!

Comment: @Aniket close but no cigar, its just testing a gyro for now but eventually I will adapt it to be used in a helicopter equipped with GPS and a 3G dongle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `angleY` before setting it in this line:

```
int angleY = angleY + angleRateY;
```

C does not guarantee that values are initialized to zero.  I presume you really want something like this:

```
int angleY = 0;
angleY = angleY + angleRateY;
```

I also assume that the second line will end up in some sort of loop in a future version.

Comment: I am getting the same result

Comment: Never mind I went back through and set all variables before calling them and it took care of the issue.